# Procedure Fast storage in DB and slow in backend

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have the following situation, I consult a stored procedure that from the database console responds in 1 seconds and when consulting from a service of my backend it takes 5 minutes.

I thought it could be construction time in the backend so the whole structure believes in the database and return an object with everything built, just read, map and send.

Query from SQL Developer

```
SET TIMING ON;

DECLARE
  ID_IN VARCHAR2(200);
  DATE_IN VARCHAR2(200);
  CORRELATION_ID VARCHAR2(200);
  OPERATION_OBJ BUSINESS_MASTER.TYPE_OPERATION;
BEGIN
  ID_IN := NULL;
  DATE_IN := '20170727';
  CORRELATION_ID := NULL;

  PKG_OPERATION_PER_DAY.SP_GET_OPERATIONS(
    ID_IN => ID_IN,
    DATE_IN => DATE_IN,
    CORRELATION_ID => CORRELATION_ID,
    OPERATION_OBJ => OPERATION_OBJ
  );

END;
/
SET TIMING OFF;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.87
```

Query from service through Postman

[image]

In the backend the only transformation that I have is that the database data is converted into an object using a Mapper with SimpleJdbcCall from Spring JDBC.

Through Postman it takes 72435 milliseconds, which is equivalent to 72 seconds.

A difference of 71 seconds between one consultation and another, I do not know what to do to optimize my code since I have done everything.

Comment: Please [post text not images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) whenever possible. You seem to have partially edited the code in the screenshot, which is a bit confusing (one `fecha_in` remains?); but are also passing different date strings - the difference in dates might explain some of it. If the problem is actually in the `SOP_GET_OPERATIONS` procedure then we need to see what that is doing.

Comment: the via postman is too vague. break down the tech stack being used and get timings for each part.

Comment: i change sqldeveloper image from text execution. The problem is not de Store Procedure because it responds in 1 second. The problem is in the backend that takes 1 minute and a half

Comment: Are you sure you send from code ID_IN := NULL; and CORRELATION_ID := NULL;? If you send other values procedure may run differently.

Comment: there is no problem with those null values ​​as I mentioned the problem I think it is between the form that receives the data and how it processes them Spring JDBC